# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS - CIFS mount via fstab very slow. 10x faster connecting in GUI

Tags: windows, cifs, gvfs, smb

I'm running an Ubuntu 12.04 LTS machine as a VM on an ESXi 5.5 server. I have two different CIFS mounts, one on a Windows 2008 R2 server and one on a Windows 2012 R2 server. I have the mounts set in /etc/fstab with the noauto switch and the mount command is called via /etc/rc.local (fstab wasn't processing quickly enough for my MythTV DVR to use the directories so I went the rc.local route). My network is running an Active Directory domain and I'm authenticating as a domain user.

I'm seeing terrible performance over CIFS to both Windows servers. Nothing about 5MB/sec in either direction and usually it's more like 1MB/sec or even slower. Running iperf against any of my Windows machines returns a rate of 98MB/sec so I know it's not a networking issue.

Here's the interesting part: If I unmount the cifs mounts, and then mount them via the GUI (Browse network etc etc, authenticate), network speeds increase exponentially - 50MB/second and higher. If I unmount and then run the mount commands that are in rc.local, traffic is again incredibly slow.

Can somebody explain why these two methods would give such different results? I'll paste code from the relevant files below. Thanks in advance.

smb.conf mountpoints:

```
//192.168.2.93/mythtv /var/lib/mythtv/recordings3    cifs  rw,user=xxxx,password=xxxx,noauto,uid=104,gid=106,file_mode=0755,dir_mode=0775 0 0
//192.168.2.91/mythtv /var/lib/mythtv/recordings4    cifs  rw,user=xxxx,password=xxxx,noauto,uid=104,gid=106,file_mode=0755,dir_mode=0775 0 0
```

Global settings of my smb.conf, including socket options I've made while troubleshooting:

```
[global]
workgroup = MYAWESOMEWORKGROUP
server string = %h server (Samba, Mythbuntu)
log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
max log size = 1000
syslog = 1
panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
dns proxy = no
security = share
max protocol = NT1
socket options = TCP_NODELAY SO_RCVBUF=65536 SO_SNDBUF=65536 SO_KEEPALIVE
follow symlinks = yes
wide links = yes
unix extensions = no
```

And finally, the lines in /etc/rc.local:

```
 mount /var/lib/mythtv/recordings3
 mount /var/lib/mythtv/recordings4
```

UPDATE:
So I've done more digging and have found more details, but still nothing that could fix it.

It looks like the GUI mount under the hood uses GVFS. I've found several other posts from people having similar issues. Some of them have the exact opposite issue where file transfers are slow in GVFS but fast in CIFS.

Transferring files to my Server 2008 R2 machine using GVFS is a bit faster than I had thought, though nothing to be excited about - about 25MB/sec. So it seems that the biggest problem is specific to my Windows 2012 R2 box (Still under 1MB/sec). I've been looking at things from the Windows angle and have disabled SMB signing, with no change in behavior. I've also noticed that the 2012 server is running SMB 3.02, and the version of Samba on my Linux machine doesn't support higher than SMB 2. I tried forcing Windows to SMB 2 with no benefit.

I've also noticed an interesting discrepency between etc/fstab settings and the results in /proc/mounts - I've been messing around with the rsize parameter in fstab and have noticed that /proc/mounts doesn't always reflect the changes correctly. With nothing set, my CIFS mounts show up in mounts with rsize=16384. If I change the rsize to 4096, this shows up correctly. But if I try anything higher than 16384, the rsize in mounts changes to 2048. Why is this? What rsize should I be using and what size does gvfs use?

It's worth mentioning that all files copied over cifs are very large 1080p recordings (from 1GB to 30GB) and the destination machine drive is formatted with the largest cluster size Server 2012 R2 would allow.

UPDATE 2: Well, I've figured out how to make it /almost/ usable. Through much research, I found that I could add a cifs.conf file to /etc/modprobe.d containing the following:

```
options cifs CIFSMaxBufSize=130048
```

After adding that file, my /proc/mounts file showed an increased buffer size in the cifs mounts, and my system almost works. I say almost because now I can actually stream DVR recordings if the system isn't doing anything else, and file copies are up to a few MB/sec transfer rate.

Comment: I have a similar problem: http://superuser.com/questions/1043449/how-to-debug-slow-samba-share-by-nautilus by gvfs the speed is only 4MB/s instead of 10MB/s. Did you manage to fix this somehow?